# Why SVG's stroke width is different from border width?

Tags: svg

Why `<svg>`'s 1px `stroke-width` is wider than `<div>`'s 1px `border-width`?

Is it possible to create an `<svg>` that looks exactly like the `<div>`below?

```html
<svg>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="red" fill="white" />
</svg>

<div style="margin: 0 0 10px 10px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red">
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's just antialiasing. You can [turn it off](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/painting.html#ShapeRenderingProperty) if you want via the shape-rendering CSS property. [Adjusting the co-ordinates by 0.5px may also work](https://cairographics.org/FAQ/#sharp_lines).

```html
<svg>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="red" fill="white" shape-rendering="crispEdges" />
</svg>

<div style="margin: 0 0 10px 10px; width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red">
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting that this doesn't work for me in Chrome 54.0.2840.100 (line is still thicker) but does work fine in Firefox and Opera.

Comment: It may be O/S dependent and/or browser dependent but in any case it's not a bug.